# White space <code> and back to line

Tags: css, textarea, whitespace

My javascript enable to "write" in `<code>` (without content editable property, behind there is a hidden `<textarea>` and javascript catch keyboard events...) and while i'm writing in this hidden `<textarea>`, text goes in line and a horizontal scroll bar appear :
[image]
I want to prevent this and make text back to line (like default `<textarea>` behaviour).

I've tried to add in my css the property `white-space : pre-wrap;` but I got this :
[image]
(textarea visible with red text color, to compare `<textarea>` behaviour and my `<code>`'s)

How to fix this and make my `<code>` behave like a `<textarea>` ? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: I think you need `word-break` or `word-wrap` rather than `white-space`, but it's impossible to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: Oh thank you ^^ I just added ``word-wrap : break-word;`` and ``word-break: normal`` and it seems to work correctly :)